# LinearLayout background color sometimes not propagating to child on Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have this STRANGE issue happening on a galaxy tab (not sure if it's also happening on other tablets, but it doesn't on my nexus 5).

Here's a preview of my layout in android studio:
[image]

The XML for a row with white background is like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_name_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/content_spacing_normal"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal"
            android:text="@string/form.label.first_name"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/first_name_value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/content_spacing_normal"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/purple"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="@string/form.placeholder.first_name"
            >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

On the Galaxy Tab, the layout looks like this:

[image]

What's even stranger is that it displayed properly a couple of times, randomly, but most of the time the white background color doesn't seem to propagate to it's children.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is possibly an issue with `android:background="@null"`, but that wouldn't explain why the `TextView` isn't always showing the white background. Try changing it to `android:background="@android:color/transparent`.

Comment: No, sadly, I already try to remove the background @null. Also try setting to transparent and no success. That's really strange.